# Error exporting state transition results to S3

Tags: amazon-s3, distribution, aws-step-functions

When enabling distributed map task and exporting the state transitions history to S3 triggers a exception with the following error message

```
An error occurred while executing the state 'Map' (entered at the event id #12). Failed to write a test manifest into the specified output bucket. | Message from S3: The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint
```

This is my the `ResultWriter` key object definition

```
/// other keys omitted...
"ResultWriter": {
        "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::s3:putObject",
        "Parameters": {
          "Bucket": "sds-qa-nv",
          "Prefix": "distributed_excecutions/"
        }
 }
```

I tried enabling `Export Map state results to Amazon S3` to save state transition to S3 and I'm expecting that the results are saved to S3 without failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This most likely occurs because the bucket you are writing to is not in the same region as the [Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/) workflow. You need to specify an S3 bucket that is in the same region.